# Stripping apostrophes from URL's

Tags: php, mysql

I'm developing a website that focuses on animals. The URL `mysite/life/ursus-maritimus` matches the value `Ursus-maritimus` in my database.

But I'd also like to display this page under the organism's common name - `mysite/life/polar-bear`

No problem, I have another table filled with common names, including 'polar bear.' I simply replace the space between the two words with a hyphen like this:

```
$CommonURL = str_replace('-', ' ', $MyURL);

[QUERY WHERE CLAUSE] WHERE Name_Common = :CommonURL
```

But what about a common name like `Grevy&#8217;s zebra`? How can I modify my WHERE clause so it ignores apostrophes, accents, etc., displaying a URL like `mysite/life/grevys-zebra`?

Comment: you don't need to  remove then, just encode\escape them

Comment: What about `mysite/life/grevy%27s-zebra`?

Comment: Dagon, if I understand correctly, encoding means the URL would look like grevy's-zebra. If I want a "clean URL" like grevys-zebra, I need to escape &#8217;. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use `str_ireplace`:

```
$MyURL="Grevy’s zebra";
$CommonURL = str_ireplace("’", "&#8217;", $MyURL);
echo $CommonURL = htmlentities($CommonURL);
//this would echo Grevy&#8217;s zebra
```

Comment: Thx; I wasn't even familiar with str_ireplace. It isn't working for me yet, but I probably just have to play with it. I want the URL grevys-zebra to match the database value 'Grevy&#8217;s zebra'

Comment: see now. is it what you want :)

Comment: Sorry, it isn't working for me. But like I said, I might just need to play with it a little more.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I understood you correctly, you want to strip out *everything* **but** the natural characters; if that's the case, then you can do something like: (the code is well commented :) )

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';

$names = array(
    'polar bear',
    'Grevy\'s zebra',
    'wet \'n wild!',
    'Nature: Alaska',
    '#myName',
    'dog % cat',
);
echo "names:\n";
print_r($names);

// "urlencode"ing them!
$names_encoded = array();
foreach($names as $name)
    $names_encoded[] = urlencode($name);

echo "\n\nnames_encoded:\n";
print_r($names_encoded);

$out = array();
foreach($names_encoded as $name_encoded)
    $out[] = preg_replace(
        array('#%[0-9a-fA-F]{2}#', '#\+#'), // finds the patterns like '%HH' (H represents an Hexadecimal digit), and '+'; the latter representing the spaces
        array('', '-'), // replace the '%HH' matches with nothing ('') and the '+' matches with '-'
        $name_encoded
    );

echo "\n\nout:\n";
print_r($out);
?>
```

An excerpt of the output would be:

```
out:
Array
(
    [0] => polar-bear
    [1] => Grevys-zebra
    [2] => wet-n-wild
    [3] => Nature-Alaska
    [4] => myName
    [5] => dog--cat
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace apostrophes and other punctuation with hyphens, you could use these three lines of code to create clean URL slugs. I've used a similar snippet for years and it's fairly sturdy. One caveat is that the third line is meant for English slugs; you'll need to add any non-English characters to the acceptable list of characters, if desired.

```
// clean, normalize, and lowercase the string
$slug = strtolower(trim(strip_tags(stripslashes($slug))));

// replace any whitespace (tabs or even multiple spaces) with hyphens
// this is MUCH more robust than just using str_replace('-', ' ', $MyURL);
$slug = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $slug); 

// convert punctuation or other non-alphanumeric characters to hyphens
$slug = preg_replace( '/[^a-z0-9-]/', '-', $slug );
```